# Xcode: unable to create symlink when archive iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to archive my project, Xcode fails with following error:

> error: unable to create symlink at
>   '/.../ios/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app'

I can build the project and also run it on an iPhone.

Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `Release-iphoneos` in your build folder might fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

The symlink command fails because you already have an existing file that the 'ln' command is trying to use.  Solution is to delete the file.  Conrad's solution works because he recommends deleting the directory containing the file (along with everything else).